# How can I remove the red X from the network icon in the Windows 7 taskbar notification area?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

How can I remove the red X from the network icon in the Windows 7 taskbar notification area?

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings (On Left Side) -> Right Click and Disable the interfaces you are not using.

I am guessing you are on Wireless and your Ethernet adapter is showing as not connected or the other way around.

Answer (score -5):

```
@Echo on
pushd \windows\system32\drivers\etc
attrib -h -s -r hosts
echo 127.0.0.1 localhost>HOSTS
attrib +r +h +s hosts
popd
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh winsock reset all
netsh int ip reset all
shutdown -r -t 1
del %0**
```

Comment: Self-deleting malicious script that ruins HOSTS file.

Comment: it might be worth explaining what this does and how to use it - I get most of it (other than the last line) and it seems to reset the hosts file to defaults but its handy to say how this fixes it.

Comment: See another Superuser post.  It worked for me. https://superuser.com/questions/661976/windows-7-shows-red-x-on-network-icon-but-im-connected