# Windows server 2016 TP5: network cross icon despite no obvious problems

Tags: networking, taskbar, windows-server

I have set up a lab server with W2016TP5, and it runs (more or less) fine. The static IP and subnet seem correct, and the DNS and DHCP servers and a bunch of Hyper-V linux VMs seem to be all fine. However, the taskbar shows permanently a "network broken" sign (see picture). Running the windows diagnostics does not identify anything wrong. Ipconfig yields the following:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (ExternalTo02):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f142:1a28:5a28:9821%24
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.1

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 2:  

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:20f3:1fc6:f5f5:f5fd
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::20f3:1fc6:f5f5:f5fd%4
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : :: 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FBE44E52-FFC9-468B-83EC-F635E09E2F5E}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Are there any conditions of misconfiguration that are not detected by usual lan diagnostics, and yet cause the taskbar net icon to raise a flag?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a red cross means that there is no physical connection to the network. It's weird that you get this error even if you have a IP address.

Please try to disable and re-enable the adapter on the server.

If it doesn't work, please check if the following link is helpful: (It's for Windows7, but it might be helpful)

[Windows 7 shows red “X” on network icon, but I'm connected](https://superuser.com/questions/661976/windows-7-shows-red-x-on-network-icon-but-im-connected)

> 1.Click Start, [click Run], type regedit, and then press ENTER.
>
> 2.Locate and then click the following registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network
>
> 3.Right-click this subkey, click Export , and then save the selected branch in a file.
>
> 4.Click the Network subkey again, and then delete the Config entry. Do not delete the >Network subkey. The Config entry will be reconstructed
>   when you restart the computer.
>
> 5.Restart the computer. You may have to manually turn off the computer.
>
> 6.The config key is re-created on the next boot up.

Hope this helps.