# Windows 7 – Red Cross on Network Icon After Incoming VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, network-adapter

After creating a New Incoming VPN Connection in my Windows 7 Ultimate 32 SP1, the Network Icon in the System Tray always shows a red cross mark even though I am perfectly connected to the LAN & Internet.

This issue is already discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/661976/windows-7-shows-red-x-on-network-icon-but-im-connected) on Super User. 
However, the solutions posted there did not work in my case.

What all I have tried so far, including earlier suggested solutions to the old question:

1. Deleted the subkey 'Config' from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network and restarted Windows. Waited for over 10 minutes but the red cross mark remains.
2. Release, Renew, FlushDNS IP address.
3. Full uninstall & reinstall of latest drives of Realtek PCIe GBE Network adapter. (Gigabyte 880GM USB3 Rev 3.1 board)
4. Disable & Re-Enable Network Adapter.
5. Updated Windows 7 SP1 with Convenience roll-up update.

Even after incoming VPN connection is established,
it continues to show the cross mark.

If I start in Safe Mode with Networking then only it’s gone but only during Safe Mode.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in Windows 7 and is there any particular update that fixes it?

Comment: Voted to reopen as OP stated answers in dupe do not work for him.

Comment: Asking the same question again will attract the same answers.  Answerers aren't likely to study all of the answers in the linked question before posting here, so we are likely to end up with total duplication of effort without adding value.  The way to avoid that is to list the things you've tried in this question, with just enough information for people to recognize that you've already tried what they were about to suggest.  I would vote to reopen if you do that.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT - I tried all your suggestions, but it did not help. Thanks for your comments  as I learnt something new. In your second comment you have mentioned same command twice. Is that on purpose? I tried that too . SFC /SCANNOW reported some corrections to corrupt files which were repaired.

Comment: I think what this is saying though is that one of your adapters (the VPN)  is not connected and when it's not connected it displays that red X to show that the network is not connected even though the other one is. Once the VPN is established, does the red X go away? Try disabling the VPN adapter and see if the red X goes away. If either, then that's what is going on. Look into disabling that red X all together... Also the other command was supposed to be `localgroup administrators networkservice /add` so you can give that a shot as well but it probably won't help though.

Comment: The Red X stays even after establishing VPN connection. I tried both the commands but it did not help. Red X goes away if I delete the VPN connection altogether and restart the PC but that defeats the purpose.